# How to code so that i will not add duplicates record instead of overwrite what is inside my txt file

Tags: java

```java
import java.io.*;

public class SaveGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String user = "John";//rewrite as String user = String.toString(Game.user)
        String compTime1 = "2";
        String compTime2 = "0";
        String compTime3 = "0";
        String compLevel = "2";
        String tokenCollected = "3";
        String flipperCollected = "2";
        String firebootsCollected = "4";
        String wingbootsCollected = "3";
        String keysCollected = "3";

        saveGame(user,compTime1,compTime2,compTime3,compLevel, tokenCollected, flipperCollected,firebootsCollected,wingbootsCollected,keysCollected);
    }

    public static void saveGame(String user, String compTime1, String compTime2, String compTime3, String compLevel, String tokenCollected, String flipperCollected, String firebootsCollected, String wingbootsCollected, String keysCollected) {
        try
        {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Game.txt",true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

            pw.print("\n" +user + "," + compTime1 + "," + compTime2 + "," + compTime3 + "," + compLevel + "," + tokenCollected + "," + flipperCollected + "," + firebootsCollected + "," + wingbootsCollected + "," + keysCollected);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Record not saved"); 
        }   
    }
}
```

What should I write so that when I add the data  with name John for example, which already exists in the `game.txt` file will not add again whereas it will overwrite the record with John in it in the `game.txt`. I found only the adding works.

Comment: You're trying to overwrite "John" but not the entire file??? Are you just trying to add another user to the file? I'm not clear on what you're asking. Try re-wording your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SaveGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        saveGame("John", "2",  "0", "0", "2", "3","2","4","3","3");
        saveGame("Andy", "2",  "0", "0", "2", "3","2","4","3","3");
        saveGame("John", "4",  "0", "0", "2", "3","2","4","3","5");
    }

    public static void saveGame(String user, String compTime1, String compTime2, String compTime3, String compLevel,
            String tokenCollected, String flipperCollected, String firebootsCollected, String wingbootsCollected,
            String keysCollected) {
        String strToBeSaved = user + "," + compTime1 + "," + compTime2 + "," + compTime3 + "," + compLevel + ","
                + tokenCollected + "," + flipperCollected + "," + firebootsCollected + "," + wingbootsCollected + ","
                + keysCollected;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        File file = new File("Game.txt");
        boolean userAlreadyExists = false;
        BufferedReader br;
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    list.add(line); // Add each line to the list                    
                }
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //System.out.println("File could not be read for processing");
            }           
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                line = list.get(i);
                if (line != null && user != null && line.toLowerCase().contains(user.toLowerCase())) {
                    userAlreadyExists = true;
                    list.set(i, strToBeSaved); // Replace the existing user data with the new data
                    break;
                }
            }           
        }

        FileWriter fw;
        try {
            if (userAlreadyExists)
                fw = new FileWriter(file); // Overwrite if the file already exists
            else
                fw = new FileWriter(file, true); // Open the file in append mode

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

            if (userAlreadyExists) {
                for (String ln : list) {
                    pw.println(ln); // Rewrite all the lines in the list
                }
            } else {
                pw.println(strToBeSaved);
            }
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Record not saved");
        }
    }
}
```

I have put the important comments in code so that you can understand it easily. Feel free to let me know in case you have any doubt.

**The content of the file after executing the program:**

```
John,4,0,0,2,3,2,4,3,5
Andy,2,0,0,2,3,2,4,3,3
```

Comment: Thank you very much, however i dont wanna be spoonfed 100% this is my modified code still have no idea why it cannot run.https://pastebin.com/BL7XzX5X

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not large you can read entire file to memory.Parse read string data to list or map of objects. Then apply new changes and re-write entire block again to file. You can pass the map or list of your objects to the writing function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to know whether a record for user "John" already exists in the file, you will need to read the file before attempting to write out a new file.

One approach is to:

1. Read the file
2. Check whether it contains a record for "John"/the user
3. If no record exists, write the file

This logic answers your question, but you probably want to merge the game data in memory with the Game.txt file rather than avoid writing the file if an existing saved game exists. Otherwise your user will never be able to save any games after his first.

Comment: I wanted to rewrite the line if the record exist

Comment: Should your file have multiple users' saved games? Your current code prevents that.

Comment: yes my file can have multiple users is just that if the user has the same name, it will overwites the exact name in the txt record if not it will add new user if the username is not in the record

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want is a merge instead of an overwrite. You should read the file into memory and locate and overwrite the line that starts with "John" (or whatever username) if it exists. If not, append John's game data to the end of the string and write it out to disk. Note that CSV is not the only way to store multiple records in a file, and may not be the best for game data.